# Pass parameter to 'document.getElementById'

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to pass div id as a parameter to `document.getElementById()`.

I tried using below function, but still not working.

```
function getID(Element_ID) {
        var el = document.getElementById(Element_ID);
        el.style.visibility = "visible";
        if(el.style.display == "none" ) {
            el.style.display = "inline";
        }
        else {
            el.style.display = "visible";
        }
        return el;//in case you want to use the element
}
```

Code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Google Charts Tutorial</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


      <script type = "text/javascript">
         google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
      </script>
       <script language = "JavaScript">
         function drawChart(DivID){
            // Define the chart to be drawn.
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Status', 'Outcome', { role: 'style' }],
               ['Executed - 70', 70,'green'],
               ['Not Executed 5', 5,'red']
            ]);
    var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [{column: 0, modifier: function () {return 'total'}, type:'string'}],
    [{column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number'}]
  );

  var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.0%'
  });

  var formatShort = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: 'short'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var amount =  formatShort.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1));
      var percent = formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / groupData.getValue(0, 1));
      return amount + ' (' + percent + ')';
    },
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

        var options = { title: 'Coveo (700341)', 'legend':'none'}; 

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(DivID));
        chart.draw(view, options);
     }
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
 <table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;width: 100%'>
 <tr align='center' valign='top'>
<td align='center' style='width:100px' valign='center' bgcolor='white'>
    <div id="container1" style="width:400; height:280"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   drawChart('container1');
</script>
</td>
 </tr>
</table>
   </body>
</html>
```

It works when I change `document.getElementById(DivID)` to `document.getElementById('container1')`. Also tried changing `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)` to `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart('container1'))`. No luck at all.

Comment: I can't see where `getID` is called

Comment: @phuzi - I have removed it from my code, thought it`ll be easy for folks to help when the code dont have any error.

Comment: As @epascarello said, we need to see the broken code to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the callback function will not pass any arguments,
use an anonymous function instead...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  drawChart('container1');
});
```

Comment: What about passing parameter which is not working. Could you be little more clear please? Please put the changes to be done here.

Comment: Just as an alternative, you can use `.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart.bind(null, 'container1'))` to create a partially applied function. Although, in all honesty, I probably wouldn't do this here as the anonymous function is easier to read and extend but it's occasionally useful.

Comment: @DeSon when you do `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` this will pass `drawChart` as the callback to be executed but no parameters (or the wrong ones) would be passed when the framework invokes the callback.

Comment: @WhiteHat - Awesome! It works fine. But can`t we pass parameter here too? Like instead of drawChart('container1') can`t we use drawChart(DivID)?